# Steady Ricci solitons with negative Ricci curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I am looking for an example of steady Ricci soliton with negative Ricci curvature. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984160/on-a-particular-solution-of-the-ricci-flow

Answer (score 2):

Steady Ricci solitons are ancient solutions of the Ricci flow. Since any ancient solution of the Ricci flow has nonnegative scalar curvature (see Corollary 2.5 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.3081.pdf) there is no an example of steady Ricci soliton with negative Ricci curvature.

Comment: what is ancient solution ?